# How to display matTooltip on mat-label with a font awesome icon in mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material, font-awesome

I tried a lot with the knowledge I have on tooltips and Angular forms but no use any help will be much appreciated thank you. Please correct me if am doing anything wrong.

Below is my code that I tried. I want to display an icon with a tooltip to explain about the selection at the end of mat-label.

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 pt-3 order-5">
    <mat-form-field name="employeeForm" [formControl]="selectFormControl">
        <mat-label>Tooltip position <i class="fas fa-info-circle" 
        matTooltip="This is simple Tooltip"></i>
        </mat-label>
        <mat-select name="country" ngDefaultControl formControlName="employee">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let employee of employees " [value]="employee">
                {{employee.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Update:  [Here is the StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-johwa2-mcczcv?file=src/app/tooltip-auto-hide-example.html)

Update 2 : BTW Please don't forget to add reference(`import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';`) to the app.module.ts file and to the provider :)

Comment: Could you please add minimal reproducible example, f.e. a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/), so it's easier to provide a solution for your question.

Comment: Sure i can do that

Comment: Hi @Roy I have updated the post with the stackblitz thank you again for your help

Comment: You cant use icon in a `mat-label` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54650693/10084605). If you want to use icon, use it with directives `matSuffix` or `matPrefix` or dont use material form field.

Comment: Quite hacky (hence why I'm not posting as an answer), but you could put the icon outside of the `mat-label` then use some CSS to shift to to the appropriate position: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-johwa2-p5sobc?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip-auto-hide-example.html Not sure how well it will stand up cross browser, and if you have several fields with icons, you may need tweak the positioning of each one

Comment: @IanA Thank you so much I think this will do the job. I was think do some hack like this but wanted to know if there is a better way to do. Thank you again this will do for now.

Comment: @tufonas Thank you for the response I got to learn something today :)

Comment: @IanA Also, just an another question as a follow up what would you suggest to do if I want the tooltip on touch device ?

Comment: I would go with @AlesD's answer as that seems a much cleaner solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the form label disables pointer events on the content. Check the class [.mat-form-field-label-wrapper](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/3318877b6f220e9740d03341277d24a5dc9426aa/src/material/form-field/form-field.scss) that is used for the label. It looks like they will remove this if you click in the link and look at the code they have a comment that mouse events should be allowed.

You can easily work around this by setting a class that enables pointer events on the icon.

For example you define a class like this.

```css
.pe {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Then just add it to the icon definition.

```html
<mat-label>Tooltip position <i class="fas fa-info-circle pe" matTooltip="This is simple Tooltip"></i>
```

Here is also a [link to a fork of your StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-johwa2-qomyk8?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip-auto-hide-example.html) where you can see it work.

Comment: The above answers is really useful fixed one of my issue. Also please don't forget to add the `import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';` to app.module.ts  and to providers.